# How to include and use pm files in perl

Tags: perl, include, package, perl-module

Ok this is how the main file uses those include pm files

```
use Dancer;
use Net::OAuth2::Client;
use HTTP::Request::Common;

sub client {
   Net::OAuth2::Client->new(
     '0', # OAuth 2.0 client_id
     '1234567890abcdef', # OAuth 2.0 client_secret
     site => 'http://www.deviantart.com',
     authorize_path => 'https://www.deviantart.com/oauth2/draft15/authorize?response_type=code',
     access_token_path => 'https://www.deviantart.com/oauth2/draft15/token?grant_type=authorization_code',
     access_token_method => 'GET',
   )->web_server(
     redirect_uri => uri_for('/auth/deviantart/callback')
   );
}
```

I have put those PM files in same directory as this but it fails because can not locate

[image]

Those files begins like this

```
package Net::OAuth2::Client;
package HTTP::Request::Common;
package Dancer;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perl expects to find `Foo::Bar::Baz` in `$PERL5LIB/Foo/Bar/Baz.pm`

It also expects the modules to come with their dependencies. Don't just copy the specific `.pm` file. Install the module properly using `cpanm` (or `cpan` or another CPAN installer).

You seem to be using Windows…

If you are using ActiveState Perl, then you probably should look to its PPM installer.

If you are using Strawberry Perl, then it will have a cpan installer and you can just run:

```
cpan Net::OAuth2::Client
```

on the command line.

Comment: Actually, it can be any directory in the `@INC` list. The `@INC` usually includes the current directory, so these could also be sub-diretories on the current directory too.

Answer (score 8):

There's a Perl variable called `@INC` that lists the directories to search for these Perl modules. Run this one liner:

```
$ perl -e 'print join ("\n", @INC) . "\n";'
```

The output will be a list of all the directories where these Perl modules can be located.

Now, you have to understand the structure of these modules. When a module says:

```
use Foo::Bar:Barfu;
```

It means there's a file called `Foo/Bar/Barfu.pm` located in one of these directories. That's how Perl knows how to find these modules. Of course, all bets are off if these modules contain binary code that must be compiled and linked with the module.

These appear to all be CPAN modules. If you are using Strawberry Perl, you can use the `cpan` command from the Console window to install these modules. Simply type `cpan` on the command line and follow the directions. You need to do this the first time, so `cpan` can configure itself.

Once that is done, you can do something like this the next time:

```
$ cpan install Dancer
```

And that will (with luck) install the Dancer module for you. This will also run all tests, and do any sort of C compiling if required.

If you're using ActiveState Perl, try using the Perl Module Manager (PMM) which should be in the Start Menu under ActiveState. You can also use ActiveState via `cpan`, but you need to do a [bit of configuring](http://docs.activestate.com/activeperl/5.8/faq/ActivePerl-faq2.html#CPAN_shell) to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to install them from cpan you should do follow steps:

1. Check if there aren't any dependences in the files: Client.pm, Dancer.pm, common.pm. You can know it from string from files which begins with use some_module; but if some others modules is used so you should use simplest way is cpan.
2. Assume that there aren't any dependences in the files. In that case you have rename these files with rule that "the name of .pm file must be the same as package name; into that file.
   There is two ways: the first in the main file you should write like so:

   use Dancer; # the name of module must be the same as file name

   use Client; # ...

   use common; # common not Common

The second way is: make some directories for every .pm file. For example if you module has name `package Net::OAuth2::Client;` so you have to make some dirs as `./Net/OAuth2/Client.pm`. The sign `::` is the same as `/` for directory path in which the module will be found.

p.s. any .pm module file in the `./` directory will be found of course if you use make right name for it.